# JSF 2.0 core tag (c:foreach) is not working

Tags: jsf-2

When I use core tag. I am getting the following error

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:347)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
com.uprr.app.xmf.client.security.core.SiteMinderHeaderFilter.doFilter(SiteMinderHeaderFilter.java:20)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
```

I am getting the following exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the JSTL on your classpath? Looks like it is missing.

Comment: Is JSTL not part of JSF 2.0 ?

Comment: No, it is very uncommon to use JSTL with JSF. Typically you will use <ui:repeat> for iteration instead...

Comment: I have give `jstl` dependency scope as `provided`. It's is working with `jetty` server but not working with `tomcat` server. I am getting the above exception

Comment: changed `jstl` dependency `<scope>runtime</scope>` it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: I have to iterate over a `Set` `ui:repeat` is not working so I am using `c:forEach` tag.

Comment: Great! But make sure to understand the differences between c:forEach and ui:repeat: http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat

Comment: @chkal: I disagree the "very uncommon" part. JSTL is extremely helpful and actually the only way when you want to conditionally build the view. You probably meant "most misunderstood" because even JSF developers who call themselves "experienced" don't understand it. Please carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681

Comment: @BalusC: Yeah, I agree. "uncommon" was not the correct term. I just wanted to say that for iteration, you "usually" use something like ui:repeat. However, there are situations, in which c:forEach makes sense. :)

Comment: @BalusC: And yes, "most misunderstood" is certainly true. :)